# What do you do when Microsoft defender flags your Excel VBA as a virus?

Tags: excel, vba, antivirus, virus

I have a very large set of Excel VBA macros that we have used at my office for literally a decade.  They facilitate building a type of prioritization model, inputting data, and then running it through the model and visualizing the results.  Recently Microsoft Defender has begun flagging these files as having a virus...that's all the info it gives me.  But it will no longer allow me to sync them to OneDrive or email them to colleagues.  I'm at a loss as to how to proceed...like literally who do you call?  Any advice would be most appreciated.

Comment: What's the exact message?

Comment: Literally just a notification that says "We detected a virus in this file and stopped syncing it.  If you have a copy on your computer, move it out of your OneDrive folder and use antivirus software to scan your computer.  Delete the infected file from your online storage, and upload the copy you scanned."  And of course, a McAfee (which is what our IT installs) scan of the file says no threats detected.

Comment: Can't you add it to the whitelist? If not, sign your project using a digital certificate from a trusted company, not self signed. Remember to keep a unsigned backup for changes, always sign a copy.

Comment: How do you whitelist a file?  I have literally hundreds of these....every model we've built using these macros for over a decade.

Comment: Alternatively, assume that there is a virus infection, load an old, virus free, copy of the macros from a backup and continue from there.

Comment: McAfee scans say no threats detected....I don't believe hundreds of files, some of which haven't been opened in months, suddenly ALL got infected simultaneously...but only the files with this particular set of VBA macros.

Comment: @jerH that's what viruses do.

Comment: What do you do or who do you call? Contact microsoft support. You can also disable the antivirus software with the false positives, and not use One Drive. You can share files through ftp transfers instead of emailing them ...  you just have to get creative to find a way to make it work.

Comment: @jerH You need to take a Divide and Conquer approach. Split the file in pieces until Defender no longer sees it as a virus. Then continue splitting until you find the issue. As an example, a few years ago, my Bitdefender antivirus did not allow me to have ```Application.Run``` in a class module but it was perfectly fine with just ```Run```. However, it took me some time to narrow down the issue. Narrowing down is your best bet.

Comment: @jerH I would start by taking one of the culprit files, and remove half of the code modules or half of the worksheets. Then test and if the file is accepted. If it is accepted, then the issue might be in the part you've removed. You then test again by removing the other part that worked (from the whole original) but this time the file should be flagged. You then proceed to split again (the one that does not work) and so on. Hope it's clear what I meant to say

Comment: @jerH Out of curiosity, did you ever found the issue and how did you solve it?

Comment: Sadly I've just been unable to open those old files.